# How to create a new stereotype for UML Class in JDeveloper?

Tags: uml, jdeveloper

I can't see anything to do so whereas stereotype can be shown ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer: JDeveloper is not capable of creating stereotypes :( Must wait for future versions.